Про тему, рему, логическое ударение и инверсию в простом предложении
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Из темы на форуме:
Предложение имеет один смысловой вариант: *не надо 
меня уговаривать*. Другое дело, что логическим 
ударением мы как бы меняем контекст (то есть 
меняется тема и рема предложения местами), но смысл 
остается одним и тем же. Напишите про тему и рему и 
их связь с логическим ударением. Что вообще такое 
логическое ударение, если оно не меняет ни 
грамматику ни смысл предложения, что оно меняет, с 
чем оно связуется?

Понимать структуру простого предложения крайне важно. И не только для того, чтобы сделать его грамматический разбор. Нужно выбрать правильный порядок слов, который может меняться в разных речевых ситуациях. Кроме того, нужно отличать простое предложение от предложения с обособлением, а это основная задача в пунктуации. Одними правилами и примерами здесь не обойдешься.
Простое предложение имеет определенную грамматическую структуру, но при этом возможно его дополнительное коммуникативное членение на тему и рему в зависимости от контекста.

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Часть 1. Краткий конспект темы по учебнику Г. И. Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка" 2013 год
Актуальное членение предложения

Кроме структурного аспекта предложения, то есть его формальной организации, которая позволяет построить предложение из определенных слов и словоформ, очень важным для общения является коммуникативный аспект предложения — его актуальное членение.

Синтаксическое членение предложения выделяет в нем главные и второстепенные члены, актуальное членение выделяет в предложении тему и рему. Тема — это предмет сообщения (о чем говорится, сообщается), а рема — это само содержание сообщения (что сообщается).
Примечание
Заметим, что простое предложение интонационно делится на две фразы, между которыми делается небольшая произносительная пауза. Сравнить:
С наступлением осени / птицы улетаю на юг. — Когда наступает осень, // птицы улетаю на юг.

Существуют разные виды коммуникативных преобразований, сопровождаемых синтаксической инверсией (обратным порядком слов):

(1) Экспрессивная препозиция ремы: Петя уехал. — Уехал ↓ Петя.
(2) Часть ремы переносится в начало предложения:  Вчера с моим другом / произошел странный случай ↓. — Странный случай ↓ произошел вчера с моим другом.
(3) Инверсия детерминанта и сказуемого: Выйдем на улицу. Здесь душно. — Выйдем на улицу. Душно ↓ здесь.
(4) Начало повествования (дислокация ремы): Посадил дед репку. Сравнить: Дед / посадил репку.
Это коммуникативно расчлененные предложения, но есть предложения, состоящие только из ремы (нерасчлененные): Стемнело. Наступило утро. Раздался телефонный звонок.
Есть нерасчлененные предложения, где фразовое ударение падает не на конечное слово, а сдвинуто в начало предложения: Тише!  Бабушка ↓ спит. Извини, что долго не звонил. В отпуск ↓ уезжал. Такие предложения требуют предшествующего контекста.
Обратим внимание на понижение тона в середине предложения (стрелка направлен вниз).
Примечание. Таким образом, возможна инверсия темы и ремы, а также перемещение фразового ударения внутри темы или ремы. Но все это интуитивный выбор носителей языка при правильном построении предложения.
Часть 2. Анализ предложения с разным контекстом
Из темы на форуме: Одинаковые фразы, но противоположные контексты
Не надо уговаривать / меня (нейтральная позиция слов). Будем считать, что это расчлененное предложение, где можно выбрать тему и рему.
Выбор логического ударения по контексту:
(1) Не нАдо меня /  уговаривать.  Я дано уже согласен.
(2) Не надо менЯ  /  уговаривать.  Уговаривайте остальных.
(3) Не надо меня уговАривать. Попробуйте убедить чем-нибудь конкретным.
В приведенном примере рема перемещена в тему (инверсия). При этом фразовое ударение падает на различные слова, которые нужно логически подчеркнуть.

"(1) Не нАдо меня / уговаривать. Я дано уже согласен." // Наоборот - Я не согласен

Всегда ли логическое ударение меняет тему с ремой? Каковы его другие функции? Что оно может поменять в предложении (смысла оно не меняет никогда, или смысл тоже может поменять)?

Ответ на комментарий
Если по Кустовой, то так. Берем нормальный порядок слов: Не надо уговаривать  меня. Сказуемое — тема, дополнение — рема. Но нас такой порядок не устраивает, и мы делаем дислокацию ремы внутрь темы: Не надо меня / уговАривать. Здесь логического ударения вообще нет, но есть конечное фразовое ударение, то есть инфинитив позиционно выделен.
Но мы хотим выделить логическим ударением другие слова, нужные по контексту. И вот здесь важно следующее: логическое ударение имеет двойственную природу, силовую и тоническую. Но чисто силовое ударение выглядит неестественно, так читать не будут. Поэтому нужное слово ставим в правильную позицию, где используется тоническое логическое ударение.
Хотите подчеркнуть не надо? Тогда запишите так: Не нАдо меня / уговаривать. Я дано уже согласен.
Очень удачное расположение слов. При реальном делении на две части логическое ударение падает на первое слово, причем оно смещено относительно  паузы. Почему? А мы всегда так выделяем слово с НЕ. Препозиция слова в начале предложения вообще классика для его отрицания.
Кроме того, мы видим явную инверсию меня в середину сказуемого, поэтому при прочтении выделим голосом не надо как первую часть сказуемого, но не инверсированное дополнение.
И никакого силового выделения, исключительно позиционное: тоническое ударение падает не на конец фразы, как обычно, а на первое слово. Это и воспринимается как логическое выделение.
Вывод. Смысл сообщения мы не меняем, но меняем расстановку слов в зависимости от коммуникативной ситуации, при этом подчеркиваем логическим ударением нужные слова.
